# Create vertex at line with reference to point

Tags: fme-form, fme-transformer

I have a line layer and point layer snapped over line. I want to create vertex at line where point lies. How to do it in FME 2018?

Comment: PointOnLineOvelayer https://www.safe.com/transformers/point-on-line-overlayer/ will split the line where your point is (you can join line back or pass the x,y coordinates to a list to create a new line with your points as vertices)

Answer (score 1):

As @Mapperz says, you can use the PointOnLineOverlayer transformer, but the drawback is that it will split the line at the point of intersection, not just add a vertex.

Another solution is the AnchoredSnapper transformer. You can use your points as the Anchor and the lines as the Candidate features:

[image]

The important part is to set Snapping Type to Segment Snapping. Snapping Distance you can set to 0 (zero) if you are sure the points lie exactly on the line features, but a small amount (say 0.1) might be a good idea.

This way you will get extra vertices on the line features, but they won't be split up. I don't believe that the lines will snap to each other, though the doc doesn't specifically state that.

There are other possible solutions (the NeighborFinder for example, or maybe something with Measures) but I think the AnchoredSnapper produces the best results with the minimum effort here.

Comment: It works well but it shift the line to point by 0.5mm.

Comment: Then I would try switching the inputs around, so that the lines are the anchors and the points are candidates to be snapped. Once they are snapped to the line, if that doesn't add a vertex to the line, you just put a second AnchoredSnapper in the original configuration (Points=Anchors) and that should do it without moving the lines.